# VSCode Extension - Get Editor Types

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to determine if the active editor is opened by git or not (i.e. files that typically end in Working Tree, Untracked, etc)

There is little difference in `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` from the original file vs the same file opened from git with the modifications view, save for one field:

```
(vscode.window.activeTextEditor as any).id
```

Which returns a string like this:

```js
'vs.editor.ICodeEditor:1,$model12'  // value for normal editor
'vs.editor.ICodeEditor:7,$model12'  // value for git editor
```

The value `7` returned for `ICodeEditor` will be consistent across all editors within a particular vscode instance, but changes depending on what editors are available.

So I'm trying to translate the magic number `7` (in this one particular case) to the EditorType

In the source code, there's an [`editorBrowser` which has the following function](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.0/src/vs/editor/browser/editorBrowser.ts#L1061-L1067):

```
export function isDiffEditor(thing: any): thing is IDiffEditor {
    if (thing && typeof (<IDiffEditor>thing).getEditorType === 'function') {
        return (<IDiffEditor>thing).getEditorType() === editorCommon.EditorType.IDiffEditor;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And [`editorCommon` has an `EditorType`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.0/src/vs/editor/common/editorCommon.ts#L683-L686):

```
export const EditorType = {
    ICodeEditor: 'vs.editor.ICodeEditor',
    IDiffEditor: 'vs.editor.IDiffEditor'
};
```

But I cannot figure out how to access any of that information from within the context of an extension.

Even [`window.activeTextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window) which returns type [`TextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor) doesn't explicitly offer up fields like `id` (which is why I had to cast to any above).  So some of the internals here might not show up in the docs / public facing interfaces.